# Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)

Tags: command-line, nautilus

When I start Nautilus as root from the terminal, I always get this error message.

[image]

```
Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
```

I need to kill the process from the terminal with Ctrl + C. I don't know if the process has something to do with Samba settings, or otherwise, it is for the installation of Dropbox or MEGASync.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question in English?

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)) and use that. Thanks.