# Failed to execute child process "net" when entering Nautilus

Tags: command-line, nautilus

When typing either of the commands `nautilus .` or `xdg-open .` into terminal, they execute correctly, but with a warning:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed:
Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

As I say, it opens the file manager correctly and I can detect no further problems. There are several instances of users experiencing this message in other questions [(1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890148/i-am-getting-the-following-errors-while-using-the-sudo-nautilus-command-as-root/890151)[(2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827218/failed-to-execute-child-process-net-no-such-file-or-directory)[(3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947783/multiple-warnings-nautilus), but each of the questions either addresses a side-issue I'm not experiencing, or simply goes unanswered.

What does this message mean, and can I do anything to prevent it?

Comment: It looks like the warning is caused by the "nautilus-share" package (a Nautilus extension). If you're not using it, you can remove that package.

Comment: … or try reinstalling it with `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus-share`.

Comment: Interesting... reinstalling with `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus-share` appears to *not* work, while calling `sudo apt-get remove nautilus-share` and then `sudo apt-get remove nautilus-share` separately appears to have resolved it.

Comment: @preferred_anon If that worked kindly post that as an answer and mark that as accepted answer.

Comment: I think it worked on my old machine, but trying it on my current one did not resolve the issue. @Yavuz Selim's suggestion worked, so I've accepted it.

Comment: Were you running as root or with sudo? That'll do it as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Error says, net command not found, so I tried **net** command. Ubuntu suggested me to install **samba-common-bin**

> Command 'net' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> apt install samba-common-bin

So, I've installed that package.

```
sudo apt-get install samba-common-bin
```

That error gone, but in my case new error was thrown.

> Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned
>   error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory
>   /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory

And then I've created directory

```
mkdir /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

Finally, I have no error.