# Nautilus doesn't open folders on desktop "Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)"

Tags: nautilus

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my computer (by the way I hate Windows with a passion and I'm so happy I found Linux. Never going back to Windows.)

From the beginning nautilus never worked.  Being new at this I thought that it was the way Linux worked.  I was trying to open folders on my desktop and nothing happened.  The only way to open folders was to open by "files".

How can I fix this issue?  I tried reinstalling nautilus but I always get this error message

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 11:23:25.561: Called "net usershare info" but it failed:
Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: 'Files' is the new name of the program `nautilus`. How do you try to open `nautilus`?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024593/failed-to-execute-child-process-net-when-entering-nautilus/1063497. OP has given solution in comments.

Answer (score 1):

> The only way to open folders was to open by "files"

means that you *can* open `nautilus`.

The following screenshot shows that when you look for `nau[tilus]` in Activities, you will find Files.

[image]

Comment: That means i canot go on the desktop and double click on a folder and open it from there

Comment: And there is no contextual menu...

Comment: @Sebastien, I understand. Those are two (maybe different) problems. You *can* start `nautilus` alias Files, but there are problems with it or with the desktop configuration. -- 1. Which version of Ubuntu are you running? 2. How was it installed? 3. Are you running Wayland or Xorg? 4. How does `nautilus` work, when you run a live session booted from your install DVD disk or USB pendrive, 'Try Ubuntu'?

Comment: @Sebastien, did you try the solution suggested in a comment by Kulfy at [Failed to execute child process “net” when entering Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024593/failed-to-execute-child-process-net-when-entering-nautilus/1063497). In a comment the OP of that question suggests removing `nautilus-share` twice.

Comment: im running ubuntu 18.4. through a DVD with with desktop 18.4 lts. i burned the os lts on the dvd and installed through with it.  i do not know what is wayland or Xorg im new at this...

Comment: This is the message i get when i try to run nautilus in thre terminal...autilus-Share-Message: 13:39:34.235: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

Comment: 1. When you run Ubuntu live from a DVD, it will use Xorg; 2. The error output makes me think that you should remove `nautilus-share` according to the link in a previous comment. Please do that and try again to start `nautilus`.

Comment: @Sebastien or sudodus - can either of you clarify the question as it currently stands at all?

Comment: @Sebastien, Zanna and I are waiting for feedback from *you*. Please help us help you :-)